# Merge dictionaries without overwriting, rather an addition of value if key equality

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Is there a way to update() a dictionnary without blindly overwriting values of the same key ? 
For example i want in my strategy to add value for the same key if i find it, and concatenate if key is not found.

```
d1 = {'eggs':3, 'ham':2, 'toast':1}
d2 = {'eggs':2,'ham':1}

dresult = d1.myUpdate(d2)

print dresult 
{'eggs':5,'ham':3,'toast':1}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this (introduced in python 2.7):

```
from collections import Counter
d1 = {'eggs':3, 'ham':2, 'toast':1}
d2 = {'eggs':2,'ham':1}
dresult = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)  #Counter({'eggs': 5, 'ham': 3, 'toast': 1})
```

If you need a version which works for python2.5+, a `defaultdict` could also work (although not as nicely):

```
from collections import defaultdict    
d1 = {'eggs':3, 'ham':2, 'toast':1}
d2 = {'eggs':2,'ham':1}
d = defaultdict(int)
dresult.update(d1)
for k,v in d2.items():
   dresult[k] += v
```

Although you could achieve an equivalent python2.? result using a dictionary's `setdefault` method...

Comment: I originally didn't think this would work if the values weren't integers -- e.g. if the values were the cost, and not the number of items, or lists or whatever -- but it seems to behave nicely.

Comment: @DSM *from the docs* Note

Counters were primarily designed to work with positive integers to represent running counts; however, care was taken to not unnecessarily preclude use cases needing other types or negative values. To help with those use cases, this section documents the minimum range and type restrictions. <snip ...>

Comment: (Hums to self) "Life is just a learning game.."  Something new every day!

Answer (score 6):

Use a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
d1 = Counter({'eggs':3, 'ham':2, 'toast':1})
d2 = Counter({'eggs':2,'ham':1})
print d1 + d2
```